Upgraded to Chai 5.x, converted whole node project to ESM modules, test run fails with unhelpful error messages
I have a node server that was originally written in 2018-19 with require and module.exports syntax. I recently upgraded to Chai 5.1, which meant I needed to convert every file in my project to ESM modules (import and export default). I have done this, and also added
  "type": "module",

and
  "mocha": {
    "node-option": [
        "experimental-specifier-resolution=node"
    ]
  }

to my package.json. I am running node 20.17.0, mocha 10.7.3, and chai 5.1.1.
I can't get any of my tests to run. The test run fails with an unhelpful error message
Exception during run: SyntaxError[ @/{path-to-my-project}/test/config_auth_spec.js ]: Unexpected token 'const'
    at compileSourceTextModule (node:internal/modules/esm/utils:339:16)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:168:18)
    at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:428:14)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:434:30)

the problem is that the error message doesn't specify a line number, and I have run the whole file through various online linters and can't pin down what the problem is.
Here's the whole file
config.auth.spec
/* ================================= SETUP ================================= */

process.env.NODE_ENV = "testing";

// import * as knexConfig from "../app/config/knexConfig";
import { mockReq, mockRes } from "sinon-express-mock";
import chai from "chai";
import { assert, expect, use, should, request } from "chai";
import { suite, test } from "mocha";
import knexCleaner from "knex-cleaner";
import sinon from "sinon";
import sinonChai from "sinon-chai";
import passport from "passport";
import chaiPassportStrategy from "chai-passport-strategy";
import users from "../db/models/users.js";
import { authConfig } from "../app/config/auth.js";
import { authCtrl } from "../app/controllers/auth.ctrl.js";

const {
  findUserByEmail,
  updateUser,
  user,
  googleLogin,
  googleStrategy,
  jwtStrategy,
  jwtLogin
} = authConfig;
const id = "325d0807-1ecf-475b-a5ab-85fea40b3f9e";
const token =
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjMyN…zE1fQ.6y9mMYVXbffHa4Q-aFUd5B3GDyyRF10iBJ28qVlEApk";
const refreshToken = "123";
const name = `firstname lastname}`;
const email = "fakeemail@test.com";
const avatar_url = "http://example.com/avatar.png";
const profile = {
  id,
  emails: [email],
  name: {
    givenName: "firstname",
    familyName: "lastname"
  },
  picture: avatar_url
};
let returnedUser = {
  id,
  name: "firstname lastname",
  email,
  avatar_url,
  type: "admin",
  google_id: "1234",
  google_token: "5678",
  created_at: new Date(),
  updated_at: new Date()
};
let req;
let doneStub = sinon.stub();

chai.should();
chai.use(sinonChai);
chai.use(chaiPassportStrategy);

suite("config : auth", function() {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  suite("use serialize / deserialize", function() {
    beforeEach(() => {
      doneStub = sinon.stub();
      returnedUser = {
        id,
        name: "firstname lastname",
        email,
        avatar_url,
        type: "admin",
        google_id: "1234",
        google_token: "5678",
        created_at: new Date(),
        updated_at: new Date()
      };
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      sinon.restore();
    });
    test("serialize returns user Id", async function() {
      await user.serialize(returnedUser, doneStub);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(doneStub, null, returnedUser.id);
    });
    test("deserialize returns user", async function() {
      const getUserByIdStub = sinon
        .stub(users, "getUserById")
        .resolves(returnedUser);
      await user.deserialize(id, doneStub);
      await getUserByIdStub;
      sinon.assert.calledWith(doneStub, null, returnedUser);
    });
    test("deserialize handles error if getUserById throws", async function() {
      const getUserByIdStub = sinon.stub(users, "getUserById").rejects("Error");
      await user.deserialize(id, doneStub);
      getUserByIdStub().catch(err => {
        sinon.assert.calledWith(doneStub, err, null);
      });
    });
  });

  suite("findUserByEmail", function() {
    beforeEach(() => {
      doneStub = sinon.stub();
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      sinon.restore();
    });
    test("returns user if found user with googleId", async function() {
      const getUserByEmailStub = sinon
        .stub(users, "getUserByEmail")
        .resolves(returnedUser);
      await authConfig.findUserByEmail(profile, token, doneStub);
      await getUserByEmailStub();
      sinon.assert.calledWith(doneStub, null, returnedUser);
    });
    test("updates user if found user without googleId", async function() {
      delete returnedUser.google_id;
      const getUserByEmailStub = sinon
        .stub(users, "getUserByEmail")
        .resolves(returnedUser);
      const updateUserStub = sinon.stub(authConfig, "updateUser").resolves({});
      await authConfig.findUserByEmail(profile, token, doneStub);
      await getUserByEmailStub();
      await updateUserStub();
      sinon.assert.calledWith(
        updateUserStub,
        profile,
        token,
        returnedUser.id,
        doneStub
      );
    });
    test("returns null if no user found", async function() {
      const getUserByEmailStub = sinon
        .stub(users, "getUserByEmail")
        .resolves(null);
      await authConfig.findUserByEmail(profile, token, doneStub);
      await getUserByEmailStub();
      sinon.assert.calledWith(doneStub, null, null);
    });
    test("handles error if getUserByEmail throws", async function() {
      const getUserByEmailStub = sinon
        .stub(users, "getUserByEmail")
        .rejects("Error");
      await authConfig.findUserByEmail(profile, token, doneStub);
      getUserByEmailStub().catch(err => {
        sinon.assert.calledWith(doneStub, err, null);
      });
    });
  });

  suite("updateUser", function() {
    beforeEach(() => {
      doneStub = sinon.stub();
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      sinon.restore();
    });
    test("updates user and returns done", async function() {
      const updateUserStub = sinon
        .stub(users, "updateUser")
        .resolves(returnedUser);
      await authConfig.updateUser(profile, token, id, doneStub);
      await updateUserStub();
      sinon.assert.calledWith(doneStub, null, returnedUser);
    });
    test("handles error if updateUser throws", async function() {
      const updateUserStub = sinon.stub(users, "updateUser").rejects("Error");
      await authConfig.updateUser(profile, token, id, doneStub);
      updateUserStub().catch(err => {
        sinon.assert.calledWith(doneStub, err, null);
      });
    });
  });

  suite("jwtLogin", function() {
    beforeEach(() => {
      doneStub = sinon.stub();
      req = {};
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      sinon.restore();
    });
    test("gets user by id and returns done", async function() {
      const getUserByIdStub = sinon
        .stub(users, "getUserById")
        .resolves(returnedUser);
      await authConfig.jwtLogin(req, { id }, doneStub);
      await getUserByIdStub();
      sinon.assert.calledWith(doneStub, null, returnedUser);
      assert.equal(req.user, returnedUser);
    });
    test("handles error if getUserById throws", async function() {
      const getUserByIdStub = sinon.stub(users, "getUserById").rejects("Error");
      await authConfig.jwtLogin({}, { id }, doneStub);
      getUserByIdStub().catch(err => {
        sinon.assert.calledWith(doneStub, err, null);
      });
    });
  });

  suite("googleLogin", function() {
    beforeEach(() => {
      doneStub = sinon.stub();
      req = {
        user: returnedUser
      };
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      sinon.restore();
    });
    test("looks up user by email if no user in req, handles error if findUserByEmail throws", async function() {
      delete req.user;
      const findUserByEmailStub = sinon
        .stub(authConfig, "findUserByEmail")
        .rejects("Error");
      try {
        await authConfig.googleLogin(
          req,
          token,
          refreshToken,
          profile,
          doneStub
        );
      } catch (err) {
        // console.log(err);
      }
      sinon.assert.calledOnce(findUserByEmailStub);
    });
    test("returns user if found", async function() {
      try {
        await authConfig.googleLogin(
          req,
          token,
          refreshToken,
          profile,
          doneStub
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      sinon.assert.calledWith(doneStub, null, returnedUser);
    });
  });
});

all of these tests were passing before I upgraded Chai and converted all the require statements to import and changed the export syntax.
Is there a way to get a more helpful error message to figure out if it's really an issue in this file specifically, or is there some other setting I need to change at the project level to get node or mocha to be able to run these test files?
